# adding data points in scattered chart by clicking on the plot area

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to create a scattered chart in Power point where I can add points to the chart by manually clicking on the plot area wherever I want rather than using the EDIT DATA option and adding precise values for X and Y coordinates in the excel sheet. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. There's no support for this built into PowerPoint.

If you're extraordinarily clever with VBA, you might be able to make something like this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Manually drawing scatter plots without using edited data is not possible, you can consider using Java to create scatter plots or write VBA code.